# javascript setTimeout not working inside if statement

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I'm writing a code to alert the user inactive when the user is idle for some time.

```
setIdleTimeout = () => {

  var timeout = 0;
  timeout = setTimeout(onExpires, 500);

  //Expires Function
  function onExpires() {
    timeout = 0;
    alert('Timed out');
  }

  //This function executes on each mouse move.
  function onMouseActivity(event) {
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(onExpires, 500);
  }
}
```

The above code works fine. But when ever I add a condition to the clearTimeout, Its not working.

example:

```
//This function executes on each mouse move.
function onMouseActivity(event) {
  var mouseSeconds =5
  if(mouseSeconds < 10) {
  //Now this is not working.
  clearTimeout(timeout);
  }
  timeout = setTimeout(onExpires, 500);
}
```

Please help me out. This is driving me crazy for hours now.
Thanks.

Comment: The argument of your `setIdleTimeout ` arrow function is a number, it should be a name instead.

Comment: `var x = 5; if (x > 10) { /* this will never happen */ }`

Comment: I updated the code with the error in the condition. My bad.

Comment: @Matt So is the issue fixed now, or are you still having an issue? If there's still an issue, where are you setting up the event to call `onMouseActivity`? Please provide all of the code needed to sufficiently reproduce your issue.

Answer (score 0):

you wrote

```
var mouseSeconds =5
  if(mouseSeconds > 10) {
  //Now this is not working.
  clearTimeout(timeout);
  }
```

mouseSeconds  is 5 it will never be bigger then 10 :) so the statement is always false.